# wso2 esb proxy service wsa:Action header invalid

Tags: wso2, handler, axis, esb

I wish to start using WSO2 ESB to allow manipulation of requests which occur between two 3rd party products.

I cannot change the calling client. I cannot change the web service.

The client is sending a request with a SOAP header which is deemed invalid by the ESB. The web service accepts the call directly from the client. It is not passing through the ESB, I see just the request come into the ESB and a reply go back to the client without the ESB calling out to the endpoint. A debug trace reveals that a handler decides that the action tag included in the header does not conform to the required standard.

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext} -  SoapAction is () {org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil} -  char set encoding set from default =UTF-8 {org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler} -  No headers present corresponding to http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler} -  http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing headers present in the SOAP message. Starting to process ... {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.client.Options} -  getAction () from org.apache.axis2.client.Options@53781b2c {org.apache.axis2.client.Options}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler} -  The wsa:Action header is present but its contents are empty.  This violates rules in the WS-A specification.  The SOAP node that sent this message must be changed. {org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481]  WARN {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper} -  triggerActionNotSupportedFault: messageContext: [MessageContext: logID=d241a239ecfe36148a4f055b69d082a8d2b599e9cd6d6ba7] problemAction:  {org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] DEBUG {org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle} -  org.apache.axis2.addressing.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(spec.FAULT_ACTION_NOT_SUPPORTED_REASON) {org.apache.axis2.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-12-24 10:51:06,481] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler} -  Error while executing the message at relaySecurity handler {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelaySecuirtyMessageBuilderDispatchandler}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The [action] cannot be processed at the receiver.
    at org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper.triggerAddressingFault(AddressingFaultsHelper.java:373)
    at org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingFaultsHelper.triggerActionNotSupportedFault(AddressingFaultsHelper.java:336)
    at org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler.extractActionInformation(AddressingInHandler.java:539)
    at org.apache.axis2.handlers.addressing.AddressingInHandler.extractAddressingInformation(AddressingInHandler.java:249)
```

The request created by the client has the following header

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action/>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:926dbf87-1f59-4fff-b1e9-341286567f8c</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>http://blahblahblah:8280/services/PassTrhuProxy1</wsa:To>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
  ...
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

We have done some testing by creating requests in SOAPUI, if we create one with a header like shown below, we can get a proper response from the service.

```
 <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
```

I have no idea how to make the ESB pass the message to the service. Is there a way?

I wonder
1. Is there a way for me to make the WSO2 ESB ignore the validation error so that I can get the message into the mediators so I can manipulate them?
2. Is there a way to turn off the validation completely?
3. Can WSO2 ESB be setup to handle this scenario out of the box? Source code change needed?

Thanks for considering my question....

Comment: I think the original reason for this is, you are not sending the SOAP action.  <wsa:Action/> is null. Try setting the property before sending to ESB. At which point you get the error? Does request hit  the proxy/sequence? Or else it fails at transport level?

Comment: Thanks for reading Ratha. Unfortunately I am unable to alter the client call.

Comment: At which point you get the error? Does request hit the proxy/sequence? Or else it fails at transport level?

Comment: I don't know how to tell; It happens before the in sequence is called so maybe transport or validation phase in the proxy. I was able to setup a custom fault sequence for the service and use that with a filter test which does a <send></send> which works - I have setup the endpoint fault delay down from the default 30 sec to 100ms to keep the service active. this is a workaround which I can use to buy some time but I need a proper solution still.

Answer (score 0):

WS-Addressing validation is sometimes annoying, but you can switch it off, by adding the following line into axis2.xml config:

```
<parameter name="disableAddressingForInMessages" locked="false">true</parameter>
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead. Initial testing failed however I found many instances of config files within WSO2 repository folder so Il will try again tomorrow. 

I am adding a section following the
 `<moduleConfig name="addressing">`
 like this

`<parameter name="disableAddressingForInMessages">true</parameter>
 <parameter name="disableAddressingForOutMessages">true</parameter> </moduleConfig>`

Comment: Not sure about many files, you need exactly this one: repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml. I added this parameter as a child of root node (axisconfig) and it works.

Comment: I was unable to see any difference in behavior with this setting in axis2.xml - I don't know it it was picked up or ignored.